# Lebesgue dominated convergence integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How would one compute this integral using Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big[\int_0^n\Big( 1+\frac{2x}{5n} \Big)e^{-x/2}dx\Big]$$
My understanding is we can't just set upper limit of the integral to be infinity and replace the integrand with just $e^{-x/2}$. But the upper limit being $n$ confuses me a lot.

Comment: Hint: $\int_A f(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} 1_A(x) f(x) $ ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\left(1+\frac{2x}{5n}\right)e^{-x/2}\cdot\mathbb1_{(0,n)}(x)$.

Clearly we have for all $n$ and $x>0$ that $0 \le f_n(x)\le f(x)=\left(1+\frac{2}{5}x\right)e^{-x/2}$

And we can prove by integrating by parts that $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx=\frac{18}{5}<\infty$

So $|f_n|\le f$ which is integrable.

Also for $n>x$ we have $f_n(x)=\left(1+\frac{2x}{5n}\right)e^{-x/2}\rightarrow e^{-x/2}$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$

Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_n(x)dx=\int\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}dx=2$

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one question to clarify, can always say that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \chi_{(0,n)}(x)=\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$? I'm assuming this is one of the identities you are using in the solution to find the limit function.

Comment: You might consider replacing $n>x$ with $x\le n$ in the second to last sentence.  Everything else looks good. +1 ... -Mark

Comment: Yes. Observe that for $x>0$ you may have only $\chi_{(0,n)}(x)$ only for $n\le x$ (which is a finite number). As soon as we have $n>x$ all the sequence terms are $1$, so the limit goes to 1.

Comment: @Dr. MV I'm not sure why do you say I should use $\le$ instead of $<$?

Comment: Because the integral extends to $x=n$.

Comment: Then I should put $(0,n]$ or $[0,n]$ in the definition of the indicator function as well. But does it matter for the value of the integral how we define the function in one or two points?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write the integral as $\int_0^\infty \left(1 + \frac{2x}{5n}\right) e^{-x/2} I\{x\le n\}\,dx$ and apply the dominated convergence theorem.